# When is a good time to use Git fetch?

Tags: git, github

If a remote repo's branch is only maintained by me, I never have to do a git fetch, is that a correct statement?

Just want to confirm my guess.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that if the remote repo only changes due to pushes from local repository, then you don't need to use `fetch`. But it's an odd question to be asking. Understand why you might need to use `fetch`, then use it when and if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a remote repo and you are the only user and you never make any changes at the remote side (such as adding a readme file or making and merging a pull request), then you are correct: you are using the remote solely for backup and all you ever have to do is push to it. This is because when you push, your remote-tracking branches are brought up to date.

But if the remote has other users who are able to make changes at the remote side (by pushing etc.), then you would need to fetch periodically in order to being your remote-tracking branches up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The git fetch command downloads commits, files, and refs from a remote repository into your local repo. If you are maintaining a particular branch of a repo and no one else is pushing any change to it, you do may not need to use `git fetch` ever. But, consider this one case - "suppose you are maintaining a branch named `dev`, it is supposed to be merged with 'master'/`main` branch. Someone else have merged some changes to the master. Now, You should fetch those changes in your local `master`/`main` branch first. You might find some conflicts that you have to resolve. Then you should merge your `dev` branch to the `master`." If this is not the case and If I understood your question correctly, you might not have to use `git fetch`.   [image]